# How to evaluate the integral $\int e^{ipx}e^{ipx} d^{3}x = 0$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, mathematical-physics

I am embarrassed to ask this question. But I came across the following in a physics book:

$$\int e^{ipx}e^{ipx} d^{3}x = 0$$

$d^{3}x = dydydz$, as @Semiclassical shows below.

This came up in the context of showing the orthogonality of eigensolutions of the Dirac equation for spinors. The author needs this relation to hold. Also, the author usually implies over all space in the context of integrals and uses a discrete summation over a finite space.

I would appreciate help as to how to see this. Especially since the LHS looks like the Fourier transform of $e^{ipx}$.

The text is Klauber, "Student Friendly QFT." The integral is in (4-27) where he is claiming the orthogonality of $\langle \psi^{(1)}|\psi^{(3)}\rangle$ (Assuming this is standard notation.)

Thanks very much.

Comment: Is that 3rd derivative of x? Or you mean $(dx)^3$

Comment: That probably is $d^3x=dx\,dy\,dz$ which is typical in physics texts.-@xuwicha

Comment: Has the LHS been transcribed correctly? Also, does the text indicate whether the integral is over all space?

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks for your interest. This came up in the context of showing the orthogonality of eigensolutions of the Dirac equation for spinors. The author needs this relation to hold. Also, the author usually implies over all space in the context of integrals and uses a discrete summation over a finite space. Regards,

Comment: The integral does not exist, what's written makes no sense mathematically. Alas, a lot of physicists insist of writing such meaningless integrals when they should write that they take a Fourier transform. If we interpret it as a Fourier transform, we can, up to normalising constants, read it as the Fourier transform of the constant $1$ evaluated in $-2p$ (or in $(-2p,0,0)$ if the $x$ and $p$ in the exponent are meant to be scalars), or the Fourier transform of $x\mapsto e^{ipx}$ evaluated in $-p$. Problem: neither of the two interpretations makes sense. The Fourier transforms are $\delta_0$

Comment: resp. $\delta_p$, and evaluating (tempered) distributions in a point doesn't make sense. Well, some people don't care and say evaluating $\delta_a$ in any point $x\neq a$ is zero.

Comment: Why do you write $e^{ipx}e^{ipx}$ instead of $e^{2ipx}$, is it written like this in the text? Can you post what book it is? btw the LHS is not a Fourier transform of $e^{ipx}$ since it depends on the wave-vector $p$! The only sensible interpretation of the integral is $\delta^{(3)}(2p)$

Comment: Which text is this? Right now we're not seeing the context ( which I'm guessing is canonical quantization of Dirac fermions.)

Comment: My 5 cents: I would guess it is a typo and it should be $e^{ipx}e^{iqx}$ in the integrand making the integral $\delta^{(3)}(p+q)$ thus giving us an ortogonality condition.

Comment: @DanielFischer Dear Daniel, I always admire your presence here. Thanks for your insight,

Comment: @Winther I think you are probably right. I added the reference and specifically what he was trying to show. Maybe your expertise will resolve it. Regards,

Comment: @Andrew I don't have that book right now so I will have to wait to see if I have it at work. But if I interpret your notation correctly then the inner-product $\left<\psi^{(1)}|\psi^{(3)}\right>$ is zero because $\left<\psi^{(r)}|\psi^{(r')}\right> \propto \delta_{rr'}$. This can be shown directly by "dotting" the two spinors together (remember the Lorentzian signature $-,+,+,+$) using the expressions in [(4-20)](http://www.quantumfieldtheory.info/website_Chap04.pdf). ...but its probably something else since the integral is not present here:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author of the text referenced. The integral over infinite volume is indeed the delta function (times (2pi)^3) and seems in this context more straightforwardly expressed as e^2ipx. (There was a pedagogic reason for expressing it as two factors in (4-27).)  In the text, the integral is actually over finite volume V and (4-27) has another factor in front of it. The integral is zero except when p = 0 (with the usual boundary conditions at the edges of V.) When p = 0, the integral is V, but the other factor is zero. Hence (4-27) is zero in any case. This could have been shown more clearly, and I am posting a comment on this on the book website.